# How to Remove " Password Condtions text " in django crispy form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have added `Password` and using `Django crispy form`. But can anyone help me with how to remove the `Password conditions text`?
Is there any easy way to remove

> Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.

> Your password must contain at least 8 characters.

> Your password can’t be a commonly used password.

> Your password can’t be entirely numeric.

> New password confirmation*

[image]

this text

Comment: @furas any idea how to do that

Comment: I don't know what is `Django crispy form`. I would use normal `HTML` to build form.

Comment: How did you build this rorm? First you should show code. Without code it is only waste of time.